# check if string changed

Tags: c, string, pointers

oK so I am proggramming in c and want to check if string changed so at first i did this :

```
 if(strcmp (ax,result)!=0){
    result=ax;
        xil_printf(result);
        xil_printf("detected");
}
    }
```

it detects only 1 time , then i figured it out that I am making the 2 pointers equal so then even if the piontee of ax changed so will happen to result since they both point at the same thing now , but i didnt want that i only wanted to change the data of result to be equal to of ppointee of ax as string ax will change later in the code so i can detect when it does.
So i tried this :

```
if(strcmp (ax,result)!=0){
    *result=*ax;
        xil_printf(result);
        xil_printf("detected");
}
    }
```

and it came out with errors , anyway how to do what i want to do that i make data of result requal to ax but they are not pointing to the same thing:
so if

```
ax-->"hello"  adrress: 232
result-->"frog"  adrress: 415
```

i detect they are diffren then i do this :

```
ax-->"hello"  adrress: 232
result-->"hello"  adrress: 415
```

BUT NOT LIKE THIS! :

```
ax-->"hello"  adrress: 232
result-->"hello"  adrress: 232   <--(they point at same thing which happens when i say result=ax)
```

So any ideas?

Comment: It is really hard to understand what you're asking, but in C, string comparison is not done with "==" but via (strcmp(str1, str2) == 0)

Comment: If needed allocate space, then `strcpy()`. If you allocated space, don't forget to free it after you're done using it.

Comment: so strcpy() will copy data from pointer to pointer but wont change memory adress they pointing at ?

Comment: @Omarshaaban: yes. Just make sure the pointers point to **valid** addresses with enough space.

Comment: just a note: if the size of your strings does not change (i.e. you know it in advance), then you can wrap them in a structure and structures are allowed to be copied with =

Comment: Solved , thanks for the help all , strcpy was the one i am looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to do `strcpy(result, ax);`

only thing is, you need to make sure result has enough room to store whats in ax

so your code will be

```
if(strcmp(ax,result) != 0){   // result is different from ax
     strcpy(result, ax);      // copy ax to result
     xil_printf(result);
     xil_printf("detected");
}
```